# How to hide the 'script' HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using HTML, and I'd like to hide the `script` tag from the user's view. When the user views the page source, the definitions should not appear. How do I accomplish this?

#### Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="My1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="My2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

I'd like to hide the definitions, any idea?

Comment: these things do not appear unless you see the source code...and hiding source code is not possible (you can reduce the code by doing most of the things in backend but you can't eliminate it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot hide HTML. If you want a closed-source solution, use a proprietary format, such as [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) or [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex).

You can, however, obfuscate your JavaScript code (you should shrinkwrap or minify it anyhow) which makes reading it harder.

Comment: any code that executes client-side is by definition accessible to the computer which executes it - it's like asking how to make a raspberry with flammable juice. It simply cannot be done. (disclaimer: I am not a genetic biologist, but I feel pretty good about that statement.)

Comment: Flash and Flex are compiled into .swf files. That makes it a lot less accessible.

Answer (score 3):

You can limit it to one script tag by making an include file that references the other scripts..

Other than that, no.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write script directly into the DOM. This also does not eliminate it (and the script to write the script would be there), but the user would have to use a DOM inspector (e.g. Firebug) to see it; it wouldn't be visible via 'view source'.

As others have said, this is just obfuscation, and simply kicks the problem down the road.

Comment: 13 years later, can you provide examples or links to resources?

Answer (score 0):

It reads to me like he's wanting to completely eliminate it, not obfuscate it.

With that said, option #2 is to not use includes, and put obfuscated javascript in his HTML.

Answer (score -1):

In my last answer I misunderstood what you meant by hiding the code.

Well as our other friends said there is no way to hide Scripts from source code.

But if you are afraid of people who want to steal your codes you can simply code your javascript instead of hiding it.

If you need a tool to code your Javascript you can use: [Shell Tool Online](http://www.shell-tools.net/index.php?op=base64_enc)

And feel safe to add your scripts.
If anyone try to copy your scripts, they will get nothing.

I hope it helps.

Comment: hide it means - it should not show in Page source...the code which we get by pressing CTRL+U or by using firebug

Comment: Your method is for hiding some thing in page view...if the code is correct it script tag should not be visible in page. if by "hide it" he means - it should not show in Page source...the code which we get by pressing CTRL+U or by using firebug it can't be done

Comment: As stated, you're only showing how to hide it from the page, not the page source.